# Unity C# reference source code within VS Code

Tags: unity, c#

Is there a way to inspect [Unity C# reference source](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference) for a particular Unity class/method within the IDE (vscode) itself, rather than having to search thorough source files in GitHub.

In VS Code I could check the documentation for a class/method, with 'jump to definition'. But it is useful if I could also see the complete source code.

Comment: I have not used VS Code so I’m not familiar with how it works. However, if you’re looking for a general solution to the problem, I normally work with Rider, which lets you simply navigate to the implementation of a compiled method in the same way you would navigate to a normal method. It will decompile the dll for you.

Comment: Good to know. But I want it for vscode. I was thinking of opening the repo as a separate project though.